# Determinant of matrix is a polynomial with unit coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with entries $(m_{ij})$. The determinant of $M$ is a polynomial in $m_{11},\dots,m_{nn}$. Are the coefficients of this polynomial all either $1$ or $-1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M=(m_{ij})$ then 
$$\det M=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\epsilon(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n m_{k\sigma(k)}$$
and since $\epsilon(\sigma)=\pm 1$ then **yes** the determinant is a polynomial in the $m_{ij}$ where the coefficients of this polynomial all either $1$ or $−1$.